# Design Preview console is Loading since last two weeeks

Tags: android-studio, loading, preview

[image]

Design preview console of my android studio stuck at loading. I can't find the solution for that even and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem a long time ago. 
So what you need to do is go to the **View** option on the top taskbar. Choose the **Tool Windows** suboption and inside it *remove and add* the Preview panel.

***View>>Tool Windows>>Preview***

This fixed the problem for me. If it does for you as well, do let me know.